# What stops MIM from sending encrypted API Token

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to understand how to use API tokens to authenticate requests to a server. I understand the general concept that a token is sent with each request and is compared to a token stored in some sort of session to authenticate the request. I also understand that the token should never be sent "out in the wild," so it is usually encrypted using SSL.

What I don't understand is how it stops man in the middle attacks. Consider the following situation.

Let's say I login to some system and want to change my email. When I login a token is generated for me, let's say the token = 1234.  So lets say I send the following command https://example.com/updateEmail?email=newemail@live.com&token=1234

For simplicity, lets assume newemail@live.com = xyz (encrypted by SSL), evilemail@live.com = abc (encrypted by SSL) and 1234 = 4321 (encrypted by SSL).

So MIM receives something like https://example.com/updateEmail?email=xyz&token=4321.

What stops MIM from getting this and changing it to https://example.com/updateEmail?email=abc&token=4321?  Wouldn't the server just decrypt 4321 to 1234, say it matches and update the email to evilemail@live.com?

Note: I am not passing user ID because it is store in a session variable on the server.

Comment: When the user logs in, a token is made for them.  `1234` would be unique for "newemail@live.com" and therefore not match "evilemail@live.com".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because security.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask generic security architecture questions. SO is for programming questions, and you haven't posted any code.

Comment: Also note that traffic over SSL is completely encrypted from between your browser to the server. Unless the MITM has the key to decrypt the connection, they won't have access to the get parameters passed. So the MITM wouldn't be able to get the email/token to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

SSL happens at the TCP Layer.  The whole request would be encrypted, so an adversary couldn't just swap bits and pieces.